# Как уменьшить таблицу HTML, CSS

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование

У меня таблица растянулась как можно ее уменьшить, чтобы прямо по центру. И ширина была не большая как указал стрелками на картинке.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот мои коды

AllStudentsAdmin.JSP

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" isELIgnored="false" %>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <style>
        <%@include file="/css/style.css" %>
    </style>
    <title>Все студенты</title>
</head>
<body>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="it">

    <h3 style="color:greenyellow" >Список всех студентов</h3>
    ${message}

    <br>
    <br>
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th bgcolor="#000000"><font color="#green" scope="col"># </font></th>
            <th bgcolor="#000000"><font color="#green" scope="col">Name </font></th>

            <th bgcolor="#000000"><font color="#green" scope="col">Surname </font></th>
            <th bgcolor="#000000"><font color="#green" scope="col">Avatar </font></th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <c:forEach var="student" items="${studentList}">
            <tr>
                <th bgcolor="#000000"><font color="#fff"  scope="row">1 </font></th>
                <td bgcolor="#000000"><font color="#fff">${student.name}</font></td>
                <td bgcolor="#000000"><font color="#fff">${student.surname}</font></td>
                <td bgcolor="#000000">
                    <c:if test="${empty student.avatar}">
                        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/ac/No_image_available.svg/768px-No_image_available.svg.png"
                             style="max-height: 200px; max-width: 200px;"/>
                    </c:if>
                    <c:if test="${not empty student.avatar}">
                        <img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/avatar?avatar=${student.avatar}"
                             style="max-height: 200px; max-width: 200px;"/>
                    </c:if>
                </td>


            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: создаем класс обертку, для него устанавливаем необходимую ширину(например, `width: 1040px`), а выровнять его по центру поможет `margin: 0 auto`

Comment: у меня есть файл CSS как можно через него сделать

Comment: в css файл добавляете `.wrapper{width:1040px;margin:0 auto}`после этого в разметку нужные вам теги оборачиваете блоком с данным классом

Comment: [рекомендую](https://htmlacademy.ru/courses) ознакомится с бесплатными курсами